# What is the best way to store a Java BigDecimal using the Google Cloud Datastore API

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I need to save financial data to cloud datastore (not through appengine, using the cloud datastore API beta); The price information is store in our object using BigDecimal.

According the api docs, only double and long are supported as numeric types.

I am concerned about saving the prices using BigDecimal's doubleValue() method due to the nature of double and precision, the other way would be using toString and saving as a String but this feels inefficient.

What do you suggest being the appropriate approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend saving it as a `String` value (especially if it is financial data). Simply because then you can restore the value with perfectly predictable result by means of `BigDecimal(String)` constructor.

See `BigDecimal(double)` constructor notes in its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)).

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is okay.  Or, if you need to sort/filter the amounts, multiply your value by the number of decimal places you need, and store it as a `Long`.

Eg: For currency amounts.  $10.23 x 100 = 1023.